# Ubuntu fails to boot because of gdm problem

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gdm3

I’ve been running into an issue today where Ubuntu refuses to start and hangs on the boot screen.  Dropping to the tty shell, I think this is because gdm fails, with the error shown in the picture.

So far, I’ve tried reinstalling my nvidia drivers and reinstalling my OS (I’ve done that 3 times) but each time, this issue reappears.  I’m running a vanilla Ubuntu 23.04 install.

How can i fix this?

[image: gdm issue]

Comment: If you can get to a shell like this, technically it didn't fail to boot.  It just failed to start the GUI.  More info might be in /var/crash

Comment: This ^^^ and the problem is very likely caused by incorrect Nvidia drivers version, incorrect installation and/or not having the modules signed (required with Secure Boot enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution- reinstalled `ubuntu-session` and it reinstalled `xwayland` and that seems to have fixed it.  Found the solution here, in the last few comments: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2006590

Edit: As a followup, I recommend not running Wayland on NVidia Cards currently; the drivers are a bit of a mess in that regard.